# Master PDF Editor won't start after installation

Tags: 16.04, pdf, libraries, master-pdf-editor

I installed Master PDF editor 4 from a .deb file downloaded from the official webpage on Ubuntu 16.04. The installation via Software was successful without any error message. However, when I start the program from the terminal I get the following error message:

```
masterpdfeditor4: error while loading shared libraries: libsane.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? I already executed

```
sudo apt install libqt5printsupport5
sudo apt install qt5-default
sudo apt install --reinstall libqt4-svg libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-test
```

as suggested in other forums, but still the same error message appears.

Comment: Also in Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS you will need ---> sudo apt install libsane1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out myself what the problem was: I accidentally installed a 32-bit version. When installing the 64-bit version everything works without a problem.